# Generate series with multiple seasonality

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, seasonality

I have to simulate time series with multiple seasonality and I don't understand how I can do it.
In particular I have to simulate:

- A series with two deterministic seasonality (each with a different period) + AR error
- A series with two stochastic seasonality (each with a different period) + AR error

Can anyone help me?

Comment: For the deterministic case, consider using two sets of dummy variables corresponding to the two seasonal periods, then independently of these generating an AR process and then adding all of them up.